# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'unicode'

Tags: python, odoo

@api.onchange('length','width')

**def** _compute_size_id(self):

```
    for s in self:
        if (s.length and s.width):
            s.size_wise = s.length * s.width
```

Comment: how i can fix this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast your variable to type int :

```py
@api.onchange('length','width')
def _compute_size_id(self):
    for s in self:
        if (s.length and s.width):
            s.size_wise = int(s.length )* int(s.width)
```

Comment: This answer addresses the current problem, but you should start earlier. Why are `length` and `width` not numbers? And one more thing: THe error looks like you use Python 2. Python 2 is no longer supported (aka dead) since the beginning of 2020. Switch to Python 3. Now!